# JQuery Ajax Contact Form Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, contact-form

Can anybody help me with this? I am not highly proficient in coding but know enough to get by. The issue is that the form can be filled out but in the telephone number field it won't accept spaces and 2) when it is filled out properly it does not return a value of "submitted".

Any help is greatly appreciated.....

```
    $("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function() {
        var str = $(this).serialize();      
        var href = location.href.replace(/dark\/|video\/|slider\/|contact\.html/g,'');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: href + "contact_form/contact_process.php",
            data: str,
            success: function(msg) {
                // Message Sent - Show the 'Thank You' message and hide the form
                if(msg == 'OK') {
                    $(this).addClass('success').find('span:eq(1)').html('success'); 
                } else {
                    $(this).addClass('error').find('span:eq(1)').html('error'); 
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

and the PHP code

```
<?php

include dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/mail.php';

error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

if($post){
    $name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $phone = stripslashes($_POST['phone']);
    $message = stripslashes($_POST['message']);





    $mail = mail(CONTACT_FORM, $phone, $message,
         "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"
        ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
        ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());


    if($mail){
        echo 'OK';
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

your `data` is the wrong syntax you need to define it and then put the key in it i.e.

```
data: {str: str},
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/